# how to fix output error in emailcheck python script

Tags: python, gmail, imap

iam trying to use a python script to do listener on gmail to get incoming emails with spicific criteria so far everything work well the script so listener and wait for the expected emai but when the email is recived i goten the following error any help will be welcome iam too beginer . already thanks.
the script used:

```
import time
from itertools import chain
import email
import imaplib

imap_ssl_host = 'imap.gmail.com'  # imap.mail.yahoo.com
imap_ssl_port = 993
username = 'USERNAME or EMAIL ADDRESS'
password = 'PASSWORD'

# Restrict mail search. Be very specific.
# Machine should be very selective to receive messages.
criteria = {
    'FROM':    'PRIVILEGED EMAIL ADDRESS',
    'SUBJECT': 'SPECIAL SUBJECT LINE',
    'BODY':    'SECRET SIGNATURE',
}
uid_max = 0


def search_string(uid_max, criteria):
    c = list(map(lambda t: (t[0], '"'+str(t[1])+'"'), criteria.items())) + [('UID', '%d:*' % (uid_max+1))]
    return '(%s)' % ' '.join(chain(*c))
    # Produce search string in IMAP format:
    #   e.g. (FROM "me@gmail.com" SUBJECT "abcde" BODY "123456789" UID 9999:*)


def get_first_text_block(msg):
    type = msg.get_content_maintype()

    if type == 'multipart':
        for part in msg.get_payload():
            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'text':
                return part.get_payload()
    elif type == 'text':
        return msg.get_payload()


server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_ssl_host, imap_ssl_port)
server.login(username, password)
server.select('INBOX')

result, data = server.uid('search', None, search_string(uid_max, criteria))

uids = [int(s) for s in data[0].split()]
if uids:
    uid_max = max(uids)
    # Initialize `uid_max`. Any UID less than or equal to `uid_max` will be ignored subsequently.

server.logout()


# Keep checking messages ...
# I don't like using IDLE because Yahoo does not support it.
while 1:
    # Have to login/logout each time because that's the only way to get fresh results.

    server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_ssl_host, imap_ssl_port)
    server.login(username, password)
    server.select('INBOX')

    result, data = server.uid('search', None, search_string(uid_max, criteria))

    uids = [int(s) for s in data[0].split()]
    for uid in uids:
        # Have to check again because Gmail sometimes does not obey UID criterion.
        if uid > uid_max:
            result, data = server.uid('fetch', uid, '(RFC822)')  # fetch entire message
            msg = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
            
            uid_max = uid
        
            text = get_first_text_block(msg)
            print 'New message :::::::::::::::::::::'
            print text

    server.logout()
    time.sleep(1)
```

the result:

```
C:\Users\PC Sony>"C:/Users/PC Sony/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe" "c:/Users/PC Sony/Desktop/elzero/elzero/# import PySimpleGUI.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/PC Sony/Desktop/elzero/elzero/# import PySimpleGUI.py", line 68, in <module>
    result, data = server.uid('fetch', uid, '(RFC822)')  # fetch entire message
  File "C:\Users\PC Sony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\imaplib.py", line 881, in uid
    typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, command, *args)
  File "C:\Users\PC Sony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\imaplib.py", line 1205, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
  File "C:\Users\PC Sony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\imaplib.py", line 963, in _command
    data = data + b' ' + arg
TypeError: can't concat int to bytes
```

Comment: try to see on high level libs, my for example - https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

Answer (score 1):

`result, data = server.uid('fetch', uid, '(RFC822)')`

should be changed to

`result, data = server.uid('fetch', str(uid), '(RFC822)')`

arguments should be of type string or bytes.
source code in imaplib.py

```
        for arg in args:
        if arg is None: continue
        if isinstance(arg, str):
            arg = bytes(arg, "ASCII")
        data = data + b' ' + arg
```